# Joining spatially AND on attribute in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I would like to use the tool "Spatial Join" in order to spatially join point (target feature) and polygons (join features) using the match option "within". In addition to the spatial join, the operation should join on an attribute identical in the two datasets. Take the following situation:
[image: join]

Imagine the colour of the points and polygons are manifested in their attribute tables in the column "colour". The red polygon should therefore be joined *only* to the red point, yellow to yellow and blue to blue (even though all three points are **within** all three polygons).

Background Info:

I'm creating a tool with ModelBuilder in order to aggregate points to groups that are within a specific distance of each other.

Comment: What have you tried?  A good question should show some research and attempt, and details of what happens when you've tried it.

Comment: Intersect and delete not matching rows from result

Comment: @FelixIP: There is nothing more deceptive than an obvious fact (A.C. Doyle). This is the solution. Are you going to pack this into an answer or should I?

Comment: Go for it. I like Sherlock

Comment: If you want to post an answer just flag for a moderator to re-open this when you have that content ready.